# Getting '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]' error, Azure SQL, Azure Functions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to access Azure SQL from Azure Functions(Python) following the documentation provided by Azure.

While the code works on cloud, it gives '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'error while running locally using Visual Studio Code.

**driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'**

Note: I am utilizing pyodbc for connecting to database, running Azure Function locally using Azure Functions Core Tools.

Comment: you need to have this driver installed in your machine: `[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] `

Comment: @Venkataraman R Just for query purpose, that means azure cloud function app (linux) already has ODBC driver!

Comment: Yes. It seems, it comes default with the linux image, used to run azure functions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/559327c2-6bd9-4337-bfe4-5d5d8273a813/install-odbc-driver-for-sql-on-function-app-linux